# Made it possible to server render without React-related markup react rc 0.10

Tags: reactjs

> Made it possible to server render without React-related markup 
>   (data-reactid, data-react-checksum) - React.renderComponentToStaticMarkup

What does it mean? Does it mean that now we do not need to inject params as JSON on a server side?

Answer (score 1):

[I answered this already on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1277).